# Restlet error. unable to run the following server-side task httpserver.serverimpl

Tags: java, restlet, httpserver

My smartphone collects GPS, Bluetooth log, then periodically send the data to server.
My server continuously receive the data by using Restlet.
However i encounter a error which i have never seen before and Google does not give any solution or hints. (my server has worked well for the past few days.)

Following message is errors i encountered.

> Unable to run the following server-side task: sun-net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange@81a5dc
>   Unable to run the following server-side task: sun-net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange@~~~~~~
>   Unable to run the following server-side task: sun-net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange@~~~~~~

Following is my code.

RestletServerMain.java

```
public void restServer(){
  try{
    Component component = new Component();
    component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, Integer.parseInt(Common.SERVER_PORT));
    component.getDefaultHost().attach(new ServerApplication());
    component.start();
  }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

ServerApplication.java

```
public class ServerApplication extends Application {
  public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
  Router router = new Router(getContext());

  router.attach("/dataprocessing1", xxx.class);
  router.attach("/dataprocessing2", yyy.class);

  return router;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be interesting to try the jetty extension (`org.restlet.extends.jetty`) of Restlet (instead of the default one).

Just add the corresponding jar file in your classpath and Jetty will be used as underlying server for your application.

Hope it will fix your issue.
Thierry